# Creating a nested for loop in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a nested for loop which will count from 1 to 10 and the second or nested loop will count from 1 to 5.

```
for ((i=1;i<11;i++));
do
     for ((a=1;a<6;a++));
     do
         echo $i:$a
     done
done
```

What I though the output of this loop was going to be was:

```
1:1
2:2
3:3
4:4
5:5
6:1
7:2
8:3
9:4
10:5
```

But instead the output was

```
1:1
1:2
1:3
1:4
1:5
2:1
...
2:5
3:1
...
and same thing till 10:5
```

How can I modify my loop to get the result I want!
Thanks

Comment: Note what you did is similar to `echo {1..5}{1..5}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You don't want a nested loop at all. Try this:

```
for ((i=1;i<11;++i)); do
    echo "$i:$((i-5*((i-1)/5)))"
done
```

This uses integer division to subtract the right number of multiples of 5 from the value of `$i`:

- when `$i` is between 1 and 5, `(i-1)/5` is `0`, so nothing is subtracted
- when `$i` is between 6 and 10, `(i-1)/5` is `1`, so 5 is subtracted

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use a nested loop in this case. What you have is a second co-variable, i.e. something that increments similar to the outer loop variable. It's not at all independent of the outer loop variable.

That means you can calculate the value of `a` from `i`:

```
for ((i=1;i<11;i++)); do
    ((a=((i-1)%5)+1))
    echo $i:$a
done
```

`%5` will make sure that the value is always between 0 and 4. That means we need `i` to run from 0 to 9 which gives us `i-1`. Afterwards, we need to move 0...4 to 0...5 with `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

I know @AaronDigulla's answer is what OP wants. this is another way to get the output :)

```
paste -d':' <(seq 10) <(seq 5;seq 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
for ((i=1;i<11;i++))
do
    a=$((a%5))
    ((a++))
    echo $i:$a
done
```

If you **really** need it to use 2 loops, try

```
for ((i=1;i<3;i++))
do
    for ((a=1;a<6;a++))
    do
        echo "$((i*a)):$a"
    done
done
```

Comment: How would I get the same result if I want to use nested loop!

Comment: ...well, actually I didn't do that, I used the correct syntax (it should be `a=$((i%5))`. Either way, the output is incorrect!

Comment: @TomFenech That is the single loop version I was trying to demonstrate